# Control doesn't comeback to Swinkworker when I call another class from it

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a class that extends SwingWorker

```
public class PowerVCImageDeployer extends SwingWorker<Boolean,String>{
protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {

        PowerVCImageDeployer imageDeployer = new PowerVCImageDeployer();
        imageDeployer.makeAConnection();
        imageDeployer.makeNameIdMap();

        // more code
        return null;
    }

public HashMap<String,String> makeNameIdMap(){

    System.out.println("I am in make NameIdMap");
    VolumeNameGetter idToName = new VolumeNameGetter();
    ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>)volIDMap.keySet();
    idNameMap = idToName.volNameGetter(list);
```

This is the trouble point. The control goes class idToName and it looks as if it doesn't come back. I have fully tested the class VolumeNameGetter using main method. The class is working good. There is no problem with it. So that looks as if once the control goes away from the SwingWorker it is unable to get it back ?? I have posted the output in the last line

```
    System.out.println("The name Id Map is "+idNameMap);
    System.out.println("Checking if the control comes back here");
    return idNameMap;


}
```

}

The output of the code is

```
I am in make NameIdMap
```

This is troubling me a lot. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanx in advance.

Debugger Output

[image]

and line number 127 is 
    return voulmeMap;

[image]

Comment: What does debugger say?

Comment: I am not able to run the debugger, the debugger hangs.

Comment: What? How does that can hang? Maybe you have a problems with concurrency and you get a deadlock etc?

Comment: When I run that in non-debug mode that runs but at a certain point during debugging it is not proceeding forward.Sorry to tell you but I am debugging for the 1st time, maybe I am doing it wrong :(

Comment: Set the `breakpoint` to the your trouble line and press the `Step into` when debugger stops on it.

Comment: SeniorJD, you made learn to use debugger today, thanx for that :)
I set the breakpoint as the last line of the class VolumeNameGetter and int the debugger winsow it is coming as a check box which is ticked.

Comment: I have posted the last section of the debugger output.

Comment: It is not the debug output, it is the `breakpoint list`.

Comment: Maybe this is it. Please see the edit.

Comment: nope. try this: http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=503